# Metal Halide Bulb with Instant On?

Tags: power-supply, power, watts

Is it possible to produce/obtain a metal halide (MH) bulb with the possibility to turn it off and on instantly - again and again? Most MH products require 30+ minutes to restrike.. Why is this?

Thanks

Comment: http://www.lightingassociates.org/i/u/2127806/f/tech_sheets/All_about_Metal_Halide_Lamps.pdf

Comment: Sure thing! It's called hot restrike.

Answer (score 1):

High intensity discharge lamps generate light by an electric arc, 
arcs are hard to form in high pressure when the lamp is hot 
there's a high pressure inside it.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to thermal conditions. For starting up, the lamps usually use between 1 to 8 minutes. For shutdown, they need to cool down, before they can strike again. The time for a restrike is dependent from the starting technology you use (either pulse- or probe-start).
Read [this Article](http://www.lrc.rpi.edu/programs/nlpip/lightinganswers/mwmhl/restrikeTimes.asp) for some more information.